# How to "catch" and on unload event when doing an onblur

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an application which when a user enters a field it then performs an AJAX validation on the field they have entered. This is triggered using an `onblur` trigger on the field. However, I want to be able to stop this firing when the user is actually navigating away from the page.

My input field looks something like

```
<input type="text" onblur="checkIt(this.value);" id="name" />
```

where the checkIt function just calls an AJAX process to validate the input. If the input is invalid then it returns an error, which is displayed in a DIV on the page. This all works great except that if the user changes their mind and decides to navigate away from the page, the error div is still displayed before they navigate away.

So in my checkIt function I want to some how be able to say,

If `event = unload` page then don't show the error and allow user to navigate away.

I am using Oracle APEX, so have `javascript` or `JQuery` available to do this

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`focusout` and `blur` didn't do what I wanted -- **to trigger a blur event of the focused element before page unload**.

use this (working) code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
  $(document.activeElement).blur();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery focusout event : Check this [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

```
<input id="test" type="text"><br>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){    
        $( "#test" ).focusout(function() {
           alert("Focus out");
        }).blur(function() {    
            alert("Blur Event");
          });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: But surely that would still fire for an onunload event, which is what I need to stop, unless I am missing something. To clarity, if they want to leave the page, then let them and do not fire the onblur/focusout, if they click somewhere else on the page, i.e are not leaving the page, then fire the onblur/focusout

Comment: If I try and catch for both events, it fires the on blur event first and then the onunload event.